# Cannot retrieve values Multiselect Widget

Tags: jquery

I am using [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) for multiple select, and I would like to retrieve the values for a later php search.

[You can find the Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cuzr6/)

```
$("#music").multiselect();

$("#SearchButton").click(function() {
            var MusicStyles = $("music").val();
            alert("Styles Selected "+ MusicStyles);
        });
```

when I hit search, I get 'undefined'.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a '#' is missing from the **click** event.
Use

```
 var MusicStyles = $("#music").val();
```